# Router Cannot See MAC Address of Devices Behind RPi Bridge

Tags: wifi, raspberry-pi, ethernet

I followed Option 1 (Same Subnet) of [this](https://www.willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/) tutorial to turn my Raspberry Pi into a WiFi-to-Ethernet Bridge. It works great, but the router cannot see the device connected behind the bridge as being connected. The IP Address of the Ethernet-connected TV I'm using shows up with the command 'arp -a' ran from my MacBook on the same network, but it is listed as having the same MAC Address as the Raspberry Pi. Is there a simple fix for the router to see the MAC Address of the device behind the bridge?

To sum up: the TV has internet access, but cannot see the other devices on my LAN.

Comment: `I followed this tutorial` Option 1 or Option 2? I'm guessing the "easier" Option 2, which would explain your issue

Comment: I'm not sure the MAC address is the real cause (of course it's related). The proxy ARP setup which mimics a bridge by routing instead doesn't allow broadcasts and multicasts to cross the router. Having separate subnets won't help. A TV needing to discover devices or a device needing to discover a TV very probably uses Bonjour/Avahi/Zeroconf which relies on multicast in the LAN. So as dhcp-helper was a DHCP relay band-aid to allow DHCP (which relies on broadcast and special setup) more band-aid might be needed for the multicast issue.

Comment: Apologies, I followed Option 1 for the Same Subnet

Comment: Thanks for the insight A.B! So It looks like I'll need a way to add multicasting?

Comment: Yes but this is difficult. The easiest way is to have the RPi be the Access Point instead of the router (which would then have to be reconfigured as a wifi STAtion client instead), then it can do real bridging (without pseudo-bridge with ARP proxy and routing) and everything would work as expected. If the router is a programmable router running hostapd then 4addr mode could be enabled to get the RPi be a client and also do real bridging (if both hardware also support it). But even this is difficult to do.

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense, thanks A.B! The router is an off-the-shelf Xfinity XFi Router, so I'll have to look into the former solution you mentioned (RPi as Access Point). Would using the Raspberry Pi as a NAT interface also work or will that give me the same issue?

Comment: routing => issue. NAT is with routing (and gets more issues).

Comment: Do you know of any well-written tutorials on setting up a WiFi-to-Ethernet Access Point? All the RPi tutorials I've seen do the reverse (Ethernet-to-WiFi AP).

Comment: Last comment: if the RPi becomes the AP, chances are you'll lose a lot of bandwidth on all of your wifi devices... It would better receive an extra NIC and be connected to the router without Wifi at all: no bridging issue. .

Comment: You can also search for avahi and "enable-reflector" in case that's enough (random page mentioning it: https://hackmd.io/@akiranet/H1gpqUAUO)

Comment: This looks like exactly what I need, thank you so much!! I'll have to read up on networking, thought googling scripts would be enough for this task but clearly that's not the case lol.

Comment: @A.B so I really appreciate the link, but it looks like this is verbatim the same code as Will Haley's lol (the tutorial I linked). I'll see what else I can find on Access Point though